# Can't edits that are not about spelling being differentiated in answers?

Tags: feature-request, edits

This is something I don't like about how edits work. Sometimes I post an answer, it gets voted up, another user comes and makes an edit that changes what I mean because "it's the right answer" in what's right or wrong hard to prove situations.
Or they change a question of mine into another question that I didn't mean to ask, and an answer with my username ends being an answer I don't believe to be right at all. Or a question I didn't want to make appears with my username because it was edited to fit another user's tastes or beliefs.

Can't the editor's edit be highlighted or something with his name, or give another solution for this?

Is it right that edits to answers or questions that change the meaning of them are allowed when they are not about spelling, formatting or adding aditional sources? Another user can post their own answers or questions, why do they have to be allowed to change the meaning of an answer or a question that got upvoted for another reason previous to the edit?

Comment: As the OP you can always rollback an edit you don't agree with.

Comment: Like rene told you can rollback, and if the user keep reediting after your rollback you can rise the issue on the specific meta before an edit war start, or you can flag a moderator at that point

Comment: @yagmoth555 Off the top of my head, edit wars get auto-flagged.

Comment: @S.L.Barth ah, learnt something, didnt knew that. thanks for the info

Comment: Is there an option to automatically rollback?

Answer (score 4):

If an edit changes the meaning of your post, you can roll it back. If it was made by a user below 2000 points and then Approved, you can overrule the Approval. This also takes back the 2 points that the editor got.

However, fixing spelling and grammar is only one thing that editors can do. Even if we could reasonably restrict them to fixing only spelling and grammar, it would be counter-productive. Some edits really expand upon a question or answer.
As a simple example, sometimes new askers are told to show us their code; they then add the code in a comment. Friendly editors can edit this code into the question, improving the question and sometimes keeping it from getting downvoted and close-voted.

So - roll back edits that you disagree with. But before you do so, make sure the edit really changes the meaning of your post. A good editor **must** respect the intentions of the OP.

Also, note that the last person to edit your post is always listed below it - their usercard is shown on the lefthand side of your own usercard, with "edited ... ago" above it. Attentive visitors will see that the post has been edited by someone other than you.

Comment: Is there an option to automatically rollback?